# Why does my program reset after it writes to this stream?

Tags: arduino

i am having an issue where my program resets itself whenever it tries to write to this stream. Any ideas why this may be occurring?
I have tried it with both Serial aswell as a StringStream class i found and both seem to be causing a crash.
I can write to both streams directly but if it occurs during the class of the HammingStream the crash occurs.

````
#include<HammingStream.h>
HammingStream::HammingStream(Stream& input_stream) {
    this->input_stream = input_stream;
    BLA::Matrix<7,4> generator_M = {1,0,0,0,1,1,0,
                                    0,1,0,0,1,0,1,
                                    0,0,1,0,0,1,1,
                                    0,0,0,1,1,1,1};
    BLA::Matrix<7,3> parity_check_M =  {1,1,0,1,1,0,0,
                                        1,0,1,1,0,1,0,
                                        0,1,1,1,0,0,1};
    this->generator_M = ~(generator_M);
    this->parity_check_M = ~(parity_check_M);
}
size_t HammingStream::write(uint8_t byte)
{
   input_stream.write(encode4(byte >> 4));
   //input_stream.write(encode4(byte & 0xf));
   return (1);
}

int HammingStream::read()
{
  if (available() == 0) return (-1);
  uint8_t nibble = decode8(input_stream.read());
  return ((nibble << 4) | decode8(input_stream.read()));
}
int HammingStream::peek()
{
  if (available() == 0) return (-1);
  uint8_t nibble = decode8(input_stream.peek());
  return ((nibble << 4) | decode8(input_stream.peek()));
}
int HammingStream::available()
{
  return (input_stream.available() / 2);
}

void HammingStream::flush()
{
  input_stream.flush();
}
uint8_t HammingStream::encode4(uint8_t nibble){
    // turn nibble into bit array for BLA::Matrix math
    BLA::Matrix<1,4>  bits;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        bits(i) = 1 << i & nibble >> i;
    }
    BLA::Matrix<1,7> output;
    BLA::Multiply(bits,generator_M, output);
    //Serial << output;
    uint8_t output8 = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        output8 = output8 | uint8_t(output(i));
    }
    return output8;
}

uint8_t HammingStream::decode8(uint8_t code){
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `HammingStream::HammingStream(Stream& _input_stream) : input_stream(_input_stream) {`

Comment: Why was that an issue before? Could it not see that i was wanting the objects variable? I thought thats what "this->" did? Thanks btw as this has fixed my problem